# Get value from input text within foreach in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a question about how to get value from input text within `foreach()`, when I execute the code it gets the last row of data inside table.

Here is the view code:

```
<?php
$count = 1;
foreach ($data as $row) {?>

<thead> 
  <th>No</th>
  <th>Out ID</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Dorm</th>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Approve</th>
  <th>Comment</th>
  <th>Action</th>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>                                                      
    <td><center><?php echo $count; ?> </td>
    <td><center><?php echo $row->IdOut; ?> </td>
    <td><center><?php echo $row->Name; ?> </td>
    <td><center><?php echo $row->Dorm; ?> </td> 
    <td><center><?php echo $row->Date; ?> </td>
    <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="approvechk"></td>
    <td><center><input type="text" name="aproverComment"></td>
    <td><center><input type="submit" name="submit" value"submit"></td>
</tr> 
</tbody>

<?php $count ++;
}
?>
```

How can I get the checked row and input from the table when submit is clicked?

Comment: thanks for edited @SiHa, sory for bad english (still learning:D)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some change in your code like:

```
<center><input type="checkbox" name="approvechk">
```

the above checkbox statement resides insides a `foreach()` loop, so you have to change its name like:

```
<center><input type="checkbox" name="approvechk[]">
```

here `approvechk[]` is used so that it can hold multiple values in it.

After that, entire input elements are not wrapped inside a form tag, so this cannot be submitted directly to server. So either wrap then in a `<form>` tag or use jquery to submit the user data to server.

Comment: Sory, i forgot put the form tag, And after i do that do i just get the input text  normaly or? for example how can i get the input text and checked field when submit in controller? do i just get it like $this->input->post('approvechk[]'); and $this->input->post('approverComment'); or how?

Answer (score 0):

The below code will work, but it would be better if you took a look at [datatables](https://datatables.net/) which is much better to work with data in tables.

```
    <?php
    $count = 1;
    foreach ($data as $row) {?>

    <thead> 
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Out ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Dorm</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Approve</th>
    <th>Comment</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr>                                                      
        <td><center><?php echo $count; ?> </td>
        <td><center><?php echo $row->IdOut; ?> </td>
        <td><center><?php echo $row->Name; ?> </td>
        <td><center><?php echo $row->Dorm; ?> </td> 
        <td><center><?php echo $row->Date; ?> </td>
<form type="post">
        <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="approvechk"></td>
        <td><center><input type="text" name="aproverComment"></td>
        <td><center><input type="submit" name="submit" value"submit"></td>
</form>
    </tr> 
    </tbody>

    <?php $count ++;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: thanks for respond, how can i get the input and checked from controller?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <thead> 
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Out ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Dorm</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Approve</th>
    <th>Comment</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
 <?php
    $count = 1;
    foreach ($data as $row) { ?>
    <tr>                                                      
        <td><center><?php echo $count; ?> </td>
        <td><center><?php echo $row->IdOut; ?> </td>
        <td><center><?php echo $row->Name; ?> </td>
        <td><center><?php echo $row->Dorm; ?> </td> 
        <td><center><?php echo $row->Date; ?> </td>
        <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="approvechk"></td>
        <td><center><input type="text" name="aproverComment"></td>
        <td><center><input type="submit" name="submit" value"submit"></td>
    </tr> 
<?php $count ++;
    }?
    </tbody>
```

>
try this method , you dont need to include whole table inside the foreach , just rows () is needed

Comment: Thanks for respond, how do i get the selected row in controller when i click submit?